# relative clause including prepositional phrase

Tags: prepositional-phrases, relative-clauses

> You don't want to throw out all that equity you have with your current audience.

I think a relative pronoun which or that is understood to be between **"equity"** and **"you"** , but was omitted to make it concise, but I'm not sure if I am correct.

So the sentence originally is :

> You don't want to throw out all that equity which/that you have with your current audience.

The relative pronoun "which/that" will be the object of the verb **have**,
and the relative pronoun "which/that" is equivalent to **equity**.

and the PP phrase **with your currect audience** can possibly be attached to the main clause or the relative clause, but in this case , it should be attached to the relative clause, as it makes more sense.

Are my knowledge above correct?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you.

Note however that *knowledge* cannot take a plural verb ('are'). I would say "Is my understanding correct?" or "Is my analysis correct?"

Comment: Thanks, without looking at the main clause, can the relative clause be viewed as: You have that(equity) with your current audience.

Comment: "You have **all** that equity with your current audience", @jammyyang: the "all" is quite significant, because "all that" is a phrase with a literal meaning ("a lot") and a emotional connotation that depends on context - often surprise or disapproval. Here the connotation is "it is so much that I am surprised that you would consider throwing it out".